# jQuery get last value on onChange

Tags: javascript, jquery

Actually I am writing this code.
I need suppose I change input field value like on input field I press from 1 to 1000 then I need last changed value i.e. 1000. But my below code is giving like first it will gives alert 1 then 10 then 100 then 1000.
Below is my code.

```
var quantity_timer;
$(".cart_quantity").on("change keypress", function () {

    var quantity = this.value; //$(this).val();
    clearTimeout(quantity_timer);
    quantity_timers = setTimeout(function() { 
        alert(quantity + " -- " + product_id);
        // Alert is giving all the value step by step  
    }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: Use `change` event only remove `keypress`

Comment: Not really clear what you are trying to accomplish here

Comment: If I remove keypress then it will work after click on screen. ?

Comment: @JohnBrad Expecting like this https://jsfiddle.net/f6zy7uwt/ ?

Comment: @John R. Can you check your js fiddle again. I changed it as per I am using. If you change suppose 1 to 1000, then I get last value 1000 in single alert.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is fix the typo in the `quantity_timer` variable used, like below:

```
var quantity_timer;
$(".cart_quantity").on("change keypress", function () {
    var quantity = this.value;

    clearTimeout(quantity_timer);
    quantity_timer = setTimeout(function() { 
        alert(quantity + " -- " + product_id);
    }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: The change is in the name of the variable used to hold the timeout function, it was misspelled so it wasn't clearing the timeout.